Wildcard not finding text
I am trying to identify words in a cell using VLookup-wildcard and referencing a table of words and an accompaniying identifier in the column beside.Unfortunately my formula is not working. Any ideas would be appreciated. example image
=VLOOKUP(""&F2&"",O:P,2,FALSE)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Main problem:
Your VLOOKUP() formula will succeed if the content of F2 does match at least ONE of the items that you have in the O-column.
e.g. =(F2=O2) should say TRUE if both cells contain e.g. the same word.

Thank you Hannu
